# Updating sql table with pdo and html

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a CMS so that it is easier for admin users to make changes to the website without having to edit the code.

So basically once the admin user has logged into the website, they should be able to add, delete and edit content. I have managed to get the add and the delete functions working, but I am struggling with the edit part.

When the user decides to edit, they are directed to a page which shows each article stored in the database and then they can click on whichever one they want to edit. The data is taken from the database by the function `$articles = $article->fetch_all();`. On a new page the script will grab the data down from mysql table using `$data = $article->fetch_data($id);`. This works and will get the data down how I want. However when I make any changes and click the update content button, I am just redirected to a blank page and no changes have been saved. I have tried to look for errors, but none are displayed and I can't see where I am going wrong. The class Article is where the functions mentioned above are stored.

I have tried a few different ways of doing the update but none actually work and I can't see where it is that I am going wrong.

This is the page the admin sees first when they decide to edit:

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');
include_once('../includes/article.php');

$article = new Article;
$articles = $article->fetch_all();


if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {

?>



<html>
    <head>
    <title>Select the content you want to edit</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/style.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>

        <br /><br />

        <h4>Select the content you want to edit</h4>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Article ID</th>
            <th>Artilce Title</th>
            <th>Article Content</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($articles as $article) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo ($article["article_id"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo ($article["article_title"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo ($article["article_content"]); ?></td>
            <td><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $article['article_id'];?>">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

</html>

<a href="index.php">Back to home</a>

    <?php

}else{
    header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
```

Once the admin clicks on one to edit they are directed to the `update.php` page:

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');
include_once('../includes/article.php');

$article = new Article;

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $data = $article->fetch_data($id);
    if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);

        if (empty($title) or empty($content)){
            $error = 'All fields are required!';
        }else{
        $sql = "UPDATE articles SET article_title = :title, 
            article_content = :article_content 
            WHERE article_id = :article_id";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);                                  
            $stmt->bindParam(':article_title', $_POST['title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
            $stmt->bindParam(':article_content', nl2br($_POST['$content']), PDO::PARAM_STR);       
            $stmt->bindParam(':article_id', $_POST['article_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);   
            $stmt->execute(); 

        header('Location: index.php');

            }

        }


    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>CMS Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/style.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>

        <br />

        <h4>Update Article</h4>


        <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>

        <small style="color:#aa0000"><?php echo $error; ?></small> 
        <br /><br />

        <?php } ?> 

        <form action ="update.php" method="post"  autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" value ="<?php echo $data['article_title']; ?>"name="title"/required><br /><br />
        <textarea  rows="15" cols="50" required name="content"> <?php echo $data['article_content']; ?></textarea><br /><br />
         <input type="submit" value="Update Content"/>




        </form>
    </div>  
    </body>
<html>

<?php

    }   

}else{
    header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
```

Looking at tutorials it looks like I am doing it correctly, but I am just redirected to a blank page each time and nothing gets updated.

Edit: After messing about with it a bit, the problem seems to be coming from the way I am getting the data down:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $data = $article->fetch_data($id);
```

This how my fetch_data function works:

public function fetch_data($article_id) {
    global $pdo;

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = ?");
$query->bindValue(1, $article_id);
$query->execute();

return $query->fetch();
```

}

I changed the sql to add since I know I could get that to work but it did the same thing(go to a blank page on form submission) until I got rid of the way I get the data down. So I know it must have something to do with but can't for the life of me figure it out

Where could I be going wrong with this?

Comment: Why are you checking for $_GET['id'] from a posted form?

Comment: Was doing that for getting the content of the selected article by the user and display it in the text area

Comment: @JacquesBarker is there a better way of getting the data from the chosen article to edit?

Comment: You're on the right track, you get the id when you go to the page from the GET but when you post the page to itself, the GET variable does not go with it. Put in a hidden form variable and change it to a POST

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after playing about with it after really helpful answers provided by Jeroen Flamman and Jacques Barker (really appreciate the help!) I managed to finally get it working by doing :

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');
include_once('../includes/article.php');

$article = new Article;

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $data = $article->fetch_data($id);
    if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);

    //if form has been submitted process it
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        //collect form data
        extract($_POST);

        if($title ==''){
            $error[] = 'This post is missing a valid id!.';
        }

        if($content ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter the title.';
        }


        if($id ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter the content.';
        }

        if(!isset($error)){

            try {

                //insert into database
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE articles SET article_title = :title, article_content = :content WHERE article_id = :id') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':title' => $title,
                    ':content' => $content,
                    ':id' => $id
                ));

                //redirect to index page
                header('Location: index.php');
                exit;

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        }

    }
        }

    }


    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>CMS Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/style.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>

        <br />

        <h4>Update Article</h4>


        <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>

        <small style="color:#aa0000"><?php echo $error; ?></small> 
        <br /><br />

        <?php } ?> 

        <form action ="update.php" method="post"  autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" value ="<?php echo $data['article_title']; ?>"name="title"/required><br /><br />
        <textarea  rows="15" cols="50" required name="content"> <?php echo $data['article_content']; ?></textarea><br /><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $data['article_id']; ?>">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Content"/>




        </form>
    </div>  
    </body>
<html>

<?php



}else{
    header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Previously I suggested $pdo was not defined. You commented that was not the case and you were right, so I looked in more detail.

The main cause is, when you post the form the 'article_id' does not get submitted. The only two fields in the form are the 'title' and the 'content'. The "id=" from the query string will not get magically included in your form. So let's add the id to the form as hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $data['article_id']; ?>">
```

We're not there yet - because the form is only processed if $_GET['id'] is set, but this time we're using POST. $_REQUEST['id'] will do the trick, it will process $_GET['id'] as well as $_POST['id'], so replace those two lines:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

In your PDO statement, replace article_id with id - and since you already assigned $title and $content let's clean that up too:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':article_title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':article_content', $content, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->bindParam(':article_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, however unfortunately the same thing still happens(just get redirected to a blank page). Also I have already declared global $pdo in the article.php file where the function fetch_data is stored so surely I would not need to do this in the update.php file as well?

Comment: thank you, unfortunately for some reason it still was not working, however after playing about with it a bit I managed to get it working which I have shown in my answer